# How to play a audio from avplayer in background when the home button is pressed....?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I done all these coding still unable play the video.....

1. `Info.plist` file adding in the `UIBackgroundModes` array the audio element.
2. And added these two methods in `AppDelegate.m`

   ```
   [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
   [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
   ```
3. and this methods in the player class

   ```
   (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
     [self becomeFirstResponder];
   }

   - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
   {
       [mPlayer pause];    
       [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
       [self resignFirstResponder];
   }

   (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
           switch (event.subtype) {
               case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
                   if([mPlayer rate] == 0){
                       [mPlayer play];
                   } else {
                       [mPlayer pause];
                   }
                   break;
               case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
                   [mPlayer play];
                   break;
               case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:
                   [mPlayer pause];
                   break;
               default:
                   break;
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: video or audio ?

Comment: I don't think you can play video while an app is in the background :P. Try observing the AppWillResignActive notification

Comment: @DatForis....I need audio....

Comment: @MOHAMMAD ISHAQ.....audio

Comment: it will be a great help...if you know it....thnks in advance......

Comment: Your issue is . you removed listing for events in viewWillDisappear , Remove all lines form it and than try.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43993793/avplayer-doesnt-pause-when-clicked-on-pause-button-if-screen-is-locked/43994158#43994158 i answered this here.

Comment: I think its all about locking the screen....but I got it right when the screen is locked and problem only exist at the time when we press the home button......I am a beginner...plz help

Comment: did you tried above link ?

Comment: @Roby solved issue ?

Comment: @MOHAMMAD ISHAQ I tried the above link.......but still no audio..

Comment: @MOHAMMAD ISHAQ I think the above provided link is mainly concerned with the lock screen....in my app when i lock the screen its working well...but fails to do so when pressed home button.....hopping for a better answer...from you...

Comment: when you press home button , App enters in background mode. So same is for lock state

Comment: @MOHAMMAD ISHAQ   I used the youtube data api for getting the list of videos.....do I require any particular permission so as to play the audio in the background...

Comment: I didn't implemented this with Youtube API , so can't say anything. Youtube videos are running in background from last month but that is inside safari not in youtube app. So i don't think it can be implemented with the app.